# Find formula, which certain truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this truth table, and I must find the right formula. (T = TRUE , V = FALSE)

Where should I start with this?

I first wrote out everything :

`A&B&C&D v A&B&C&-D v -A&-B&C&-D`  etc...

But then I was told, that I can solve this even easier. Any suggetions?

**EDIT: the last column A is the truth value of the correct formula.**

[image]

Comment: I would title the last column something besides $A$ as you have already used $A$.  Say we call it $F$.  You might make a column of the truth value of $F \iff C$ and find some inspiration.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/how-to-find-the-logical-formula-for-a-given-truth-table

Comment: If you compare the desired output to $A \iff C$ you are getting close.

Comment: I got $(a\land c)\lor (a\land \neg b\land d)\lor  (\neg a\land b\land \neg c)\lor (\neg a\land b\land \neg d)\lor (\neg a\land \neg c\land \neg d)$ just in case you want to control your result.

Comment: @Listing : hehe Im not sure, I made the Karnaugh map, but don't understand how to solve it

Comment: @Jaanus,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#Solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution of Karnaugh map:

[image]

$(A\land C)\lor (A\land \neg B\land D)\lor  (\neg A\land B\land \neg C)\lor (\neg A\land B\land \neg D)\lor (\neg A\land \neg C\land \neg D)$

Comment: Why does 0110 not connect with 1110? I connected them in my map...can you explain? Is my solution wrong, or there are two possibilities?

Comment: What my solution was :  A&C v A&-B&D v B&C&-D v -A&-B&-D v -A&B&-C

Comment: @Jaanus,Yes there are two possibilities,both correct...but you have to use only one of them in final expression

Comment: So my solution is also correct, by the looks of it?

Comment: @Jaanus,it should be $B\land C\land \neg D$ instead $B\land \neg C\land \neg D$

Comment: @Jaanus,I didn't see well that you wrote correct expression so your solution is ok