# I need to find the formula for the truth table by using ∨ ∧ ¬

Tags: logic

This is the process I did, but I’m not sure if the procedure is correct:

P | Q | ?
F | F | F
F | T | T
T | F | T
T | T | F

(¬P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q)
=> ((¬P ∧ Q) ∨ P) ∧ ((¬P ∧ Q) ∨ ¬Q)
=> (P ∨ Q) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q)

Comment: The formula **must** be $P \lor Q$...

Comment: But a general procedure is: consider the rows in which the table outputs T and write a disjunct  corresponding to each row where the single disjunct is a conjunction made of prop letter (if it occurs in the row with T) or negation of a prop letter (if it occurs in the row with F).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I wrote the last value of the table wrong. It’s supposed to be F

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/how-to-find-the-logical-formula-for-a-given-truth-table)

Answer (score 2):

My apologies if this should be a comment, I don't have the rep. It's been a while since I learned this, but isn't it going to be $P \oplus Q$ or $P \veebar Q$, the XOR/exclusive or operator? Unless there is more information that's not available, that fits all of your datapoints.

Comment: Your are right. It’s my mistake, I forgot to mention that I must only use ∨  ∧ ¬. I will edit the post.

Comment: Ah I see. In that case I agree with what you found - $(P\vee Q)\wedge (\neg P\vee \neg Q)$ works.